# API call using openweathermap not working - call does not even show under Network in Console

Tags: html, css, reactjs, openweathermap

I am trying to return temperature results for a city and it does not seem like my API call is working. I am not sure if the problem is with my API key or my code. Please advise how I can fix this. If I open my console and go to the network settings, the api call does not come up after I enter the city name in the web app and press enter.

App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const apiKey = 'API KEY'; //I inserted my API key here
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([{}]);
  const [city, setCity] = useState('');

  const getWeather = (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'ENter') {
      fetch(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=s{city}&units=imperil&APPID=${apiKey}' //this API I copied from the video tutorial
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setWeatherData(data);
          setCity('');
        });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <input
        className="input"
        placeholder="Enter City..."
        onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
        value={city}
        onKeyPress={getWeather}
      />

      {typeof weatherData.main === 'undefined' ? (
        <div>
          <p>
            {' '}
            Welcome to weather app! Enter the city you want the weather of.
          </p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>{weatherData.name}</p>
          <p>{Math.round(weatherData.main.temp)}℉</p>
          <p>{weatherData.weather[0].main}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 25px;
 }

 .input {
padding: 15px;
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid lightgrey;
border-radius: 6px;
font-size: 16px;
 }

 .input:focus{
  outline: none;
 }
```

Comment: Maybe try logging to see if the event or something even exists, so put a log in your if statement for example

Comment: And maybe the problem is in the typo "ENter" or you have to change the onKeyPress to: onKeyPress={() => getWeather(e)}

Comment: I changed the typo and still nothing happens. If I change my code to onKeyPress={() => getWeather(e)}, I get the following error: 'e' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your code

It should be

```
if (event.key == 'Enter')
```

in the `getWeather` function